# VSTO Add-In for Outlook alter text in info box

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Like to change the info text when creating a meeting in outlook using VSTO.

It is simple to change subject, location and body using Outlook.AppointmentItem but not the info text. Meaby I just do not know what it is called.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That header is not exposed for the programmatic access.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for displaying MailTips.

MailTips are informative messages displayed to users in the infobar in Outlook Web App and Outlook 2010+ when a user does any of the following while composing an e-mail message:

- Add a recipient
- Add an attachment
- Reply or Reply all
- Open a message from the Drafts folder that's already addressed to recipients.

You can configure MailTips on the Exchange server side, see [Configure MailTips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff872400%28v=exchsrvcs.149%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.